# Adding to div with jQuery & HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm having some issues with my code. I'm trying to remove a link (a) and then after that add a new link (a) with different text.

Here's the code

HTML:

```
<label for="name" class="control-label">Username:</label> 
@<a href="<?php echo $username ?>">
    <p class="text-info-username">
        <?php echo strtolower($username) ?><i class="icon-star"></i></a></p>
<div class="controls-username">
    <a href='#' id="edit-username" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#edit-username').click(function() {
 var text = $('.text-info-username').text();
 var input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="' + text + '" id="editTextBox" />')

 $('.text-info-username').text('').append(input);
 $('#edit-username').remove();
 $('<a href='#' id="update" class="btn">Update</a>').appendTo('.controls-username');
 $('<br /><br />').insertAfter('.controls-username');

});
```

Comment: The typical implementation of this would be to have both links in the HTML and .hide()/.show() them with jQuery so only one shows up at a time.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the .html method instead of the .text to append html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you had an issue with your quotations.  Here's a revised version of your JS:

```
$('#edit-username').click(function() {
 var text = $('.text-info-username').text();
 var input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="' + text + '" id="editTextBox" />');

 $('.text-info-username').text('').append(input);
 $('#edit-username').remove();
 $('<a href="#" id="update" class="btn">Update</a>').appendTo('.controls-username');
 $('<br /><br />').insertAfter('.controls-username');

});
```

Also a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhcf39oo/

Comment: Missing semicolon in line 3

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it myself as well. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple concerns:

1. Your HTML element nesting is wrong with the first -Tag.
2. Your missing a semicolon in javascript after the definition of input.
3. Fiddling with the html from javascript is not really good. Its harder to debug later on and not necessary. Use an approach of already delivering the html with the initial pageload and use css/javascript to hide and unhide (show) them appropriately.

I've made an quick jsFiddle for you:

```
$('#button-edit-username').click(function() {

  // Hide the user list
  $('.text-info-username').hide();

  // Show a form with pre-filled contents
  var text = $('.text-info-username').text();
  $('#editTextBox').attr('placeholder', text);
  $('#editForm').show();

  // Swap the visible link
  $('#button-edit-username').hide();
  $('#button-update').show();

});

$('#button-update').click(function() {

  // Hide the form again
  $('#editForm').hide();

  // Show the user list again
  $('.text-info-username').show();

  // Swap the visible link
  $('#button-update').hide();
  $('#button-edit-username').show();


  // Report success.. implement save function here
  var newName = $('#editTextBox').val();
  alert('Successfully edited .. '+ newName +' !');    

});
```

You can see the full example at https://jsfiddle.net/8xhwugvu/, showing such an approach.

[image: JSFiddle]